# Super Simple CodeIgniter Auth with 'remember me'

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

My website has no user registration (members are pulled through from an offline db) and the area that you can login to doesn't hold very sensitive information.

So I want a basic login with a remember me function.

• After checking input against the DB, I plan to store their `user_id, name, email` in a session.

• For the remember me, I'd store a cookie with value = `user_id:randomcode`. The random code is generated at login and stored in a field on their user record.

Is this secure enough? or how could it be improved without getting too complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `user_id:randomcode` only once and generate a new one when the old is used. Read [Persistent Login Cookie Best Practice](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/).

Comment: For sessions, is it enough to just check `if(isset(session['user_id']))` on each page or should I actually be making sure there is a matching user in the DB (checking this every page load)

Comment: @gio: I think that is ok, since the session data is stored on the server and not on the client.

Comment: And would it be ok to to use php's uniqid() function to generate the auth code?